# Error comparing two double variables in PHP

Tags: php

I have encountered this strange behaviour in PHP.

My code is:

```
$pra        = $this->PercentualeRicaricoApplicata; // 37
$current    = floatval($currentPercentage->RicaricoPercentuale); // 37
$lower      = floatval($lowerPercentage->RicaricoPercentuale); // 27
            
myecho(gettype($pra) . ' - ' .gettype($current) . ' - ' . gettype($lower));
echo '<br>pra <= current: ';var_dump($pra <= $current); 
echo '<br>pra >= current: ';var_dump($pra >= $current);
echo '<br>current >= pra: ';var_dump($current >= $pra);
echo '<br>pra <= current: ';var_dump(37.00 <= 37.00); 
echo '<br>pra > lower: ';var_dump($pra > $lower);
```

and I get these results:

```
double - double - double

pra <= current: bool(false)
pra >= current: bool(true)
current >= pra: bool(false)
pra <= current: bool(true)
pra > lower: bool(true)
```

I can't come around why (pra <= current) and (current >= pra) aren't working with double variables.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump()` on the actual values? Are you aware of problems with comparisons of floating point numbers? https://3v4l.org/qRqiP

Comment: I can't reproduce those results with the stated input values: https://3v4l.org/rUsEH. You might want to var_dump _those_ values and check they contain what you think they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to both  I have been directed to this solution ([bccomp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php)):

```
echo '<br>pra: ';var_dump($pra);
echo '<br>current: ';var_dump($current); 
echo '<br>lower: ';var_dump($lower); 
echo '<br>bccomp current: ';var_dump(bccomp($pra, $current, 2));
echo '<br>bccomp lower: ';var_dump(bccomp($pra, $lower, 2));
```

thus obtaining the expected behavior

```
pra: float(37)
current: float(37)
lower: float(27)
bccomp current: int(0) //equal
bccomp lower: int(1) // greater
```

Comment: OK. What was the reason we were unable to reproduce your original problem, though? Did you discover that?

Comment: It might have been due to the fact I was getting values from a json_decode. Because when I tried to hardcode values ($pra = 37;) everything was working fine.

Comment: Well, simply the fact it came from JSON does not, by itself cause a specific issue normally. You'd have to check what was actually in the original JSON, and then what values it was decoded to, to see if that caused an issue. But I don't see how it would, unless you have a specific example you can share where it went wrong.